# Prove $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2^2\cdot4!}-\frac{\pi^4}{2^4\cdot6!}+\frac{\pi^6}{2^6\cdot8!}-\frac{\pi^8}{2^8\cdot10!}+\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to prove this equation $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2^2\cdot4!}-\frac{\pi^4}{2^4\cdot6!}+\frac{\pi^6}{2^6\cdot8!}-\frac{\pi^8}{2^8\cdot10!}+\dots$$
So I got the series for the left side of equation $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n \cdot \pi^{2n+2}}{2^{2n+2}\cdot (2n+4)!}}$$ but I do not know how to come to end.

Comment: It looks like you are have a some slight variation off of the Taylor series of $\cos x$ evaluated at $x = \frac {\pi}{2}$

Comment: Multiply the whole equation by $\pi^2/2^2$ and then you can figure out the pattern easily.

Comment: The command of Mathematica `Sum[x^(2*k)*(-1)^(k - 1)/2^(2 k)/(2 k + 2)!, {k, 1, Infinity}]` performs $$-\frac{-x^2-8 \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+8}{2 x^2}.$$ I leave the rest on your own.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*} & =\frac{\pi^2}{2^2\cdot4!}-\frac{\pi^4}{2^4\cdot6!}+\frac{\pi^6}{2^6\cdot8!}-\frac{\pi^8}{2^8\cdot10!}+\dots 
\\ & =\frac{\frac{\pi^4}{2^4\cdot4!}-\frac{\pi^6}{2^6\cdot6!}+\frac{\pi^8}{2^8\cdot8!}-\frac{\pi^{10}}{2^{10}\cdot10!}+\dots}{\frac{\pi^2}{2^2}} 
\\ & = \frac{(1-\frac{\pi^2}{2^2\cdot2!}+\frac{\pi^4}{2^4\cdot4!}-\frac{\pi^6}{2^6\cdot6!}+\frac{\pi^8}{2^8\cdot8!}-\frac{\pi^{10}}{2^{10}\cdot10!}+\dots)+\frac{\pi^2}{2^2\cdot2!}-1}{\frac{\pi^2}{2^2}} 
\\ & = \frac{\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{2^2\cdot2!}-1}{\frac{\pi^2}{2^2}} 
\\ & = \frac{\frac{\pi^2}{2^2\cdot2!}-1}{\frac{\pi^2}{2^2}} \frac{1}{2!}-\frac{2^2}{\pi^2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi^2}.\end{align*}

The fact used here is that

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots.$$

Comment: @LalitTolani I do not think you understand what the align environment means and does. I edited it for you.

Comment: @Gary Thankyou, I will see and learn it